# Google DataStudio: Reuse existing connectors inside a new connector which I'm currently developing

Tags: looker-studio

I need pull data from "Google Sheets" and "Analytics", for which I'm creating a connector, and I would like to know if it's possible re-use existing "Google Analytics" & "Google Sheets" provided by DataStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-using native connectors inside a Community Connector is not possible at the moment.

However, you can achieve the same result by using [Apps Script Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). Most of the native connectors in Data Studio have a corresponding Advanced Service in Apps Script.

For your specific use case, you can use the [Analytics Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics) and the [Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets). Before using them in your code, make sure that you follow the [instructions to enable the advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). The [Fusion Table Community Connector](https://github.com/google/datastudio/tree/master/community-connectors/fusion-tables) is an Open Source example that shows how to use an advanced service in a Community Connector.